# How can I decode a message that was encrypted with a one-time pad if I have the key?

Tags: decryption, one-time-pad

Can I decode a message that was encrypted with a one-time pad if I have the key used to encrypt it? If so, how?

Comment: Normally it would just be a matter of XORing the key and the message. The specific details would depend on the form of the key - if it's binary, it's probably a bitwise XOR. If it's text, it might be bitwise, or at letter level (so message "A" with key "X" gives "Y")

Comment: yes, and that key you have is the only way to decrypt it.

Comment: If you tell us the format, we could write a code implementation to actually perform the decryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The one-time pad is usually employed as a symmetric encryption, i.e., encryption key and decryption key are the same. It is often as simple as applying `XOR` of key and message.

Note that the one-time pad suffers from some problems:

- You can use a key exactly one time, otherwise the encryption is broken
- There is no protection against altering the encrypted message
- You need a way to exchange the one time pad keys in a secure way.